# Contact form Phone Number format Javascript

Tags: javascript

This piece of code lets me write a phone number to my contact form as (XXX) XXX-XXXX format. (working example is at https://www.fxmerkezi.com/ucretsiz-danismanlik/)

But I need it to be done like 0XXXXXXXXXX first character must be 0 and no letters or any other characters shouldt be allowed.

This is the code in my head tags;

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery-input-mask-phone-number@1.0.0/dist/jquery-input-mask-phone-number.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#yourphone').usPhoneFormat({
                format: '(xxx) xxx-xxxx',
            });

            $('#yourphone2').usPhoneFormat();
        });

    </script>
```

And this is the file jquery-input-mask-phone-number.js:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.usPhoneFormat = function (options) {
    var params = $.extend({
        format: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
        international: false,

    }, options);

    if (params.format === 'xxx-xxx-xxxx') {
        $(this).bind('paste', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var inputValue = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            if (!$.isNumeric(inputValue)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                inputValue = String(inputValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
                $(this).val(inputValue);
                $(this).val('');
                inputValue = inputValue.substring(0, 12);
                $(this).val(inputValue);
            }
        });
        $(this).on('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                return false;
            }
            var curchr = this.value.length;
            var curval = $(this).val();
            if (curchr == 3) {
                $(this).val(curval + "-");
            } else if (curchr == 7) {
                $(this).val(curval + "-");
            }
            $(this).attr('maxlength', '12');
        });

    } else if (params.format === '(xxx) xxx-xxxx') {
        $(this).on('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                return false;
            }
            var curchr = this.value.length;
            var curval = $(this).val();
            if (curchr == 3) {
                $(this).val('(' + curval + ')' + " ");
            } else if (curchr == 9) {
                $(this).val(curval + "-");
            }
            $(this).attr('maxlength', '14');
        });
        $(this).bind('paste', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var inputValue = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            if (!$.isNumeric(inputValue)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                inputValue = String(inputValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3"));
                $(this).val(inputValue);
                $(this).val('');
                inputValue = inputValue.substring(0, 14);
                $(this).val(inputValue);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}(jQuery));

Comment: That plugin only supports two formats of phones. I suggest you drop it completely, learn from it and write your own version. This regex line is the key: `inputValue = String(inputValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. just simply define your textbox as below which will allow only 11 digits with starting 0.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $( "#number" ).keypress(function(e) {
  
   if(this.value.length == 0 && e.which != 48){
     return false
    }
    if(e.which < 48 || e.which > 57 ||  this.value.length > 10){
     return false
    }
   
 }); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
<input type="text" id="number" name="country_code" pattern="[0]{1}[0-9]{10}">
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but its not limiting the maximum number

Comment: then you need to add the keypress event on this and check. i will create the code and will give you in some time

Comment: Thank you so much that works perfect. Can I ask 1 more thing please? Is it possible to have the form field like

As starting 0 will be there and the user will type the rest.

0(andusertypes10moredigits)

Comment: yes it is possible just define value 0 by default and then when user enter other 10 digits you can simply concate that value.

Comment: I just really don't know how to do it, can you please assist me with editing your code? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Hmeanshu, can you help me with this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write regex to match the format you want,

```
    let regex = /[0]\d+/gi;
    let match = regex.exec(e);
    if(match && match.length == 11){

        return true; // match found with 11 digits number starting with 0
    }
    else{
    alert('invalid number'); // no match found
    }
```